# c lang error in xcode 5.0 after adding "fno-objc-arc" for some classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm-clang

I am working on Xcode 5.0,i copied JSON library files in to my project which are built with non arc, so i added complier flag "fno-objc-arc"for those JSON library compiler sources.
After doing this i am getting apple LLVM 5.o error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'fno-objc-arc'
Command    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Pleas help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Try add "-fno-objc-arc" instead

Comment: Please be careful if you are copy/pasting the '-fno-objc-arc' flag. Dash character may be misleading if you are copying from another document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that's a command line option, [and it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327070/what-do-these-symbols-fno-objc-arc-mean), you need to prefix it with a hyphen, such as with:

```
clang -fno-objc-arc ...
```

If you just use `fno-objc-arc`, it's going to think it's a file name you want compiled, and complain bitterly that no such file exists, as indeed it seems to be doing with the `no such file or directory: 'fno-objc-arc'` error.

Comment: I'm getting error 'clang: error: no such file or directory: 'clang''. I'm working on Xcode 6.4.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, you should post a question so it gets more eyeballs on it but it *looks* like you might have the command line `clang clang something` (i.e., duplicate `clang`). That'd be my first guess but, as stated, a question will get you more exposure and probably better answers, even if they *are* still guesses :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is ***no new line character*** after `-fno-objc-arc.` You can be assured by entering `-fno-objc-arc` and *click somewhere around instead of hitting enter/return key.*

This got my problem fixed!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. It appears to be an answer to a different question only tangentially related, and one that you never bothered to ask save as a comment to another answer.